# Creating a New DataFrame Column and Filling it with an If Statement - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, moving-average

The desired outcome would be to have a new column with header 'xOver', whereby the values within xOver are determined by an if statement.

The values of xOver will either be: 1, 2, or NaN.

Value will be 1 if: data['Close'] > data['sma_5'] and data['Close'][-1] < data['sma_5']

Value will be NaN if that criteria is not satisfied.

Value will be 2 if another if and statement criteria is fulfilled (but for simplicity we can just ignore that for the purposes of solving this problem).

This is the data frame, which is called: data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTAwR.png)

This is the code I have tried thus far:

```
import pandas as pd 
import mplfinance as mpf
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel('SPY.xlsx', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)


#Create the moving avergae 
data['sma_5'] = data['Close'].rolling(33).mean()

print(data)

def xOver(data):

    if data['Close'] > data['sma_5'] and data['Close'][-1] < data['sma_5']:
        return 1
    else:
        np.nan

data['xOver'] = xOver

print(data)
```

Which returns this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE5oL.png)

SPY.xlsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlnR5.png)

Comment: We need a [mcve] to be able to reproduce. That means: 1/ the dataframe **as text** so that we can copy/paste, 2/ enough code to reproduce the problem and 3/ the observed and expected result.

Comment: The data frames do not post well as text, hence why I included screenshots of them.

Comment: Do not try to add code or dataframe data in comments, but please edit the question. Code in comment is hard to read and copy.

Comment: I mean the data doesn't really matter too much, could be any values. Just included the data frames as headers and to assess the output of the above code.

Comment: how do you add text df's - just added and it has pasted poorly / the guidance of how to post online is weak. Hence the photos which I provided.

Comment: Please post enough code **IN THE QUESTION ITSELF** so that we can reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, with the solution being:

```
data['xOver'] = np.where((data['Close'].shift(+2) < data['sma_5'].shift(+1)) 
                         & (data['Close'].shift(+1) > data['sma_5'].shift(+1))
                         & (data['Close'] > data['sma_5'].shift(+1)),
                         data['sma_5'],np.nan)
```